# Django Admin - Use Bing Maps instead of OSM

Tags: django, mapping, admin, bing-maps, geodjango

I need to change the base map that is displaying when I view geographic data in the Admin pages.  As it stands it is currently using openstreetmap.   I would like to use BING maps via their API.  I have successfully done this in another part of my application, but I can't figure out how to do it in the Admin interface.

Does anyone have an example I could use?  It doesn't even have to be bing maps, just anything that overrides the default map.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://mattmakesmaps.com/blog/2013/05/01/django-add-mapquest-tiles/) website provides an example of how to do this with Mapquest instead of the OSM tiles. While I didn't adapt it for Bing, I did adapt it to work with Django 1.8.6 running on Python 3.5.0.

It will require creating (or modifying an existing) Django admin template to get this to work, but OpenLayers provides an [html](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/bing-maps.html) page you can use for the Bing reference. I don't have enough experience with OpenLayers to know how to do this.

Basically:

- Subclass GeoModelAdmin, and point to your new template by editing `admin.py` (more info on this in the [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/admin/) docs), and replace `GeoTest` with your model's name:

  ```
  class BingGeoAdmin(django.contrib.gis.admin.GeoModelAdmin):
      map_template = 'gis/admin/bing.html'

  admin.site.register(GeoTest, BingGeoAdmin)
  ```
- Create a `bing.js` using Django's existing `osm.js` as a reference, which involves changing the base_layer block to the new Bing layer.
- Create a `bing.html` template, pointing to the `bing.js` file.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  We didn't end up making the change just yet which is why I haven't repsonded, but your idea looks great.